# array length returning zero inside props to the child component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

itemsLength variable is returning zero to pagination component this.state.items.length just above the pagination component shows a count of 6 but it shows zero on pagination component

here is the parent component

```
 {this.state.items.length}
                <Pagination
                    itemsLength={this.state.items.length}
                    currentPage={0}
                    pageCount={2}
                />
```

the child pagination component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Pagination extends Component {

    pageArray = [];

    componentDidMount = () => {
        console.log(this.props.itemsLength);
        let { itemsLength, currentPage, pageCount } = this.props;
        let pages = Math.ceil(itemsLength / pageCount);

        console.log('itesm length ', itemsLength);


        for (let i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
            this.pageArray.push(i + 1);
        }

        console.log('page array ', this.pageArray);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {
                    this.pageArray.map(
                        page => {
                            return (<button>page</button>);
                        }
                    )
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Pagination;
```

sandbox link for [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/su02x)

Comment: Hey the sandbox works

Comment: yes, the code is functioning but my problem is I am not getting the proper value of itemsLength prop that I send to the pagination component. if you see there are two consoles in component did mount and both of them show zero whereas the right value should be 6

Answer (score 1):

I dont think its problem with the code, its probably the `codesandbox`

Reason,

- whats you saying in question happens when i update the `shop.jsx` file (probably any other also)
- BUT, WHEN I MODIFY `pagination.jsx` file and the output updates everything seems work fine

Comment: @ash1102 please confirm it, and mark as answer if it helped

Comment: the problem was encountered on vs code version:1.45.1 I merely transferred it to sandbox to provide the whole code. How did you make it work could you write the snippet please.

Comment: there is no problem with IDE . I was filling my pageArray inside componentDidMount and it was being called only once and that too after render and so my pageArray shows zero at the very beginning and not updated again. now i renamed component did mount to myFun and calling it before return inside render and it works fine.Thank you for your help @aXuser264